# Resetting Infinite Scroll for show new results retrieved via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll, jquery-ias

I've a filter form that on change fills a container div (#results) with new filtered results from a DB. But after changing the filter the [Infinite Ajax Scroll](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/) plugin shows in the *second page* the results of the first search. On change event I need to totally reset the old results and show only the new ones. I tried many solutions but nothing done. I know there [methods](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/methods.html) to do that but I can't understand how to use them in my code (check the comments).

```
    // Form select inputs: on change call the filter
    $("select").on("change", function() {
       setTimeout(function() { 
         ias.destroy(); 
       }, 1000);
       ias.bind();
       filter();
    });

    // Filter: Ajax call that returns new results by a SQL query to the DB
    var filter = function() {
      var formData = form.serializeObject();
      $.ajax({
        url: "/libs/filterData.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        cache: false,
        success: function(results) {
          $("#results").html(results);
        }
      });
    };

    // IAS configuration
    //var initializeIas = function() {
      var ias = jQuery.ias({
        container: "#results",
        item: ".result",
        pagination: ".page-nav",
        next: ".page-nav a"
      });
    //};

//initializeIas();
```

Tried also [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22093845/1252920) but doesn't work.

Similar problem [here](https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll/issues/68).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20404493/932282

Comment: I tried this solutions http://stackoverflow.com/a/22093845 because the other ones are old, now there's version 2 of the plugin. It doesn't work... (check the updated code above)

Answer (score 0):

Try re-initializing IAS within the succes-handler:

```
// Filter: Ajax call that returns new results by a SQL query to the DB
var filter = function() {
  var formData = form.serializeObject();
  $.ajax({
    url: "/libs/filterData.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
    cache: false,
    success: function(results) {
      ias.destroy(); 
      $("#results").html(results);
      ias.bind();
    }
  });
};

// IAS configuration
var ias = jQuery.ias({
      container: "#results",
      item: ".result",
      pagination: ".page-nav",
      next: ".page-nav a"
  });
```

Comment: Hi @mhu: I tried your code, and also to remove seTimeout but it doesn't work, that is, the plugin loads in the second page the old results.

Comment: Just tried, the same as above :\  I can't get where is the problem!

Comment: Please make a fiddle for further assistance

Comment: Thanks for the support @mhu. I've uploaded the sample project here http://bit.ly/1pmdci2. Try to change form select "Price" to (i.e.) 7000 and you will see that the second page shows the old and wrong results. Let me know if you need something.

Comment: As you configured it IAS uses the href of the ".nav a" element to load the next page. You always return `?pagina=2`, so IAS always loads page 2.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this issue, I'm facing same issue. Pls advise.