# How do I bind and unbind infinite-ajax-scroll so other jQuery works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ias

**Note:** I know this is a common issue and a lot has been written about this but I can't seem to fix it.

My Shopify store uses Ajax call's to add products to the cart and jQuery to update the front-end. I recently installed [infinite-ajax-scroll](https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll) but this brought some issues.

When scrolling down to the products loaded by infinite-ajax-scroll, and then click on the add to cart button, the ajax calls & jQuery updates don't work anymore, it redirects me to the cart page.

Here's the inline script I'm using to activate IAS:

```
<script>
  var ias = jQuery.ias({
    container:  '#products',
    item:       '.single-product',
    pagination: '.pagination-custom',
    next:       '.next'
  });

  ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension({
    src: '{{ "spiffygif_36x36.gif" | asset_url }}'
  }));
</script>
```

This is the code ([ajaxify.js](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0656/8697/t/7/assets/ajaxify.js?9064) line 161 - 194) that's responsible for adding the product to the cart:

```
Shopify.addItemFromForm = function(form, callback, errorCallback) {
  // Unbind IAS
  ias.destroy();

  var params = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/add.js',
    data: jQuery(form).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(line_item) {
      if ((typeof callback) === 'function') {
        callback(line_item, form);
      }
      else {
        Shopify.onItemAdded(line_item, form);
      }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
      if ((typeof errorCallback) === 'function') {
        errorCallback(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus);
      }
      else {
        Shopify.onError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus);
      }
    }
  };
  jQuery.ajax(params);

  var variant_id = params.data.split('=')[1]
  $( "#var-id-" + variant_id + " " + "#in-cart-indicator" ).removeClass( "not-in-cart" ).addClass( "triangle-top-right" );

  // Bind IAS
  ias.bind();
};
```

I've added the [`bind`](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/methods.html#bind) and [`unbind`](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/methods.html#unbind) method based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404493/reset-disable-infinite-scroll-after-ajax-call), but without success.

What am I doing wrong?

You can take a look at the page in question [here](http://goo.gl/AMIgcP).

Comment: Maybe this comment from the post you referenced may be helpful: This won't work if the loadMoreItems function takes shorter than 1000 msecs, because then destroy would be called after the bind –  mhu Jun 26 at 10:58

Comment: What would you suggest I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by reinitialising `ajaxifyShopify` every time the new products finished rendering using infinite-ajax-scroll's [`rendered`](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/events.html#rendered) event.

Copy and paste the following code in `collection.liquid`:

```
<script>
var ias = jQuery.ias({
  container:  '#products',
  item:       '.single-product',
  pagination: '.pagination-custom',
  next:       '.next'
});

ias.on('rendered', function() { 
  jQuery(function($) {
    ajaxifyShopify.init({
      method: '{{ settings.ajax_cart_method }}',
      wrapperClass: 'wrapper',
      formSelector: '#addToCartForm',
      addToCartSelector: '#addToCart',
      cartCountSelector: '#cartCount',
      toggleCartButton: '.cart-toggle',
      useCartTemplate: true,
      btnClass: 'btn',
      moneyFormat: {{ shop.money_format | json }},
      disableAjaxCart: false,
      enableQtySelectors: true
    });
  });
})
</script>
```